# Dialog confirmation not working in Selenium RC with C#

Tags: c#, selenium, nunit, selenium-rc, selenium-ide

I am trying to confirm a dialog pop-up in Selenium RC using C#. I recorded my steps in Selenium IDE and exported to C# (RC). The important part of the code is the following:
            selenium.Click("id=editCustomerForm:tbl_registrations:0:disableRegistrationCmdImg");
Assert.AreEqual("undefined", selenium.GetConfirmation());

The script always fails on the "Assert.Are..." line with the following error message:

SeleniumTests.test.TheTestTest:
Selenium.SeleniumException : ERROR: Command execution failure. Please search the user group at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/selenium-users for error details from the log window.  The error message is: result is undefined

When I run the same two commands in IDE (click and assertConfirmation), it's working. Can someone help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just try calling the function `selenium.GetConfirmation()` to accept the modal message.
Do not use Assert.AreEqual

Comment: Already tried that. I tried Console.Write(selenium.GetConfirmation); the code failed at that line with the same error message.

Comment: I also tried this with JUnit and the same error appears. Maybe it's something wrong with the web application I am testing.